# Optimizing CSS and JS on MVC6 Dot Net Core

Tags: javascript, css, optimization, .net-core

I am presently trying to streamline an MVC .NET Core project. The first time load for a user is between 4 and 5 seconds which by many metrics appears to be on the sluggish side.

Currently i have tried.....

- Image optimization and compression (Optimizilla).
- Cache headers for jpg and png. (Not really for first load but still nice)
- gZip Compression for static files and responses.

Yet i'm still in the 3 - 4 second loading time range.

I have 5 large images for my main carousel. Ranging between 222Kb and 96Kb. The other "large" files are site.min.js (184Kb) and site.min.css (96Kb).

The total volume of data transferred, as reported by Chrome dev tools, is 1.6Mb. The aforementioned files consist of 1.1Mb of this data.

1) What strategies are available to trim down javascript libraries and css files? i.e. remove redundant snippets. (Automatically???)

2) Does .NET core provide any other optimisations that can be exploited here?

3) Are there any exotic approaches like async loading of images or minified css files with Dot Net Core?

Regards

Comment: I'm not sure whether .NET Core offers anything out of the box (though I would be more than happy to be proven wrong). Are you providing all of your JS and CSS to the user when they hit the site? By that I mean, from the file names `site.min.js` and `site.css` I'm guessing that you serve the user with _everything_ they need up front. It might be worth creating separate bundles per page/area of your site. Unless you're building a single page application (in which case, take a look at the SPA and JavaScript services libraries)

Comment: Related: [link 1](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/LightweightBundlingMinifyingAndCompressionForCSSAndJavaScriptWithASPNETCoreAndSmidge.aspx) and [link 2](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/WebOptimizerABundlerAndMinifierForASPNETCore.aspx)

Comment: If you are using ES2015 compliant JavaScript you could look at [tree shaking](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking) to remove redundant script. With regard to loading resources such as images, js, css etc. using a Content Delivery Network to host your resources could dramatically improve concurrency and therefore reduce the overall time to fetch.